# Building a Docker container for Golang code: package PACKAGE_NAME is not in GOROOT

Tags: docker, go

I built a small Golang application and I want to run it on a Docker container.

I wrote the following Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY ./* .
RUN go env -w GO111MODULE=on

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/docker-gs-ping" ]
```

However, when I run the command:

```
docker build --tag docker-gs-ping .
```

I get the errors:

> #16 0.560 found packages controllers (controller.go) and repositories (csv_file_repository.go) in /app
> #16 0.560 main.go:4:2: package MyExercise/controllers is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/MyExercise/controllers)

I want to mention that the package controllers exists in my working directory and all files associated with this directory are placed in MyExercise/controllers folder.

Do you know how to resolve this error?

Edit:
This is the directory tree:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── REDAME
├── controllers
│   └── controller.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── logging
│   └── logger.go
├── main.go
├── models
│   └── location.go
├── output.log
├── repositories
│   ├── csv_file_repository.go
│   ├── csv_file_repository_builder.go
│   ├── csv_file_repository_builder_test.go
│   ├── csv_file_repository_test.go
│   ├── repository_builder_interface.go
│   ├── repository_interface.go
│   └── resources
│       └── ip_address_list.txt
└── services
    ├── ip_location_service.go
    ├── ip_location_service_test.go
    ├── rate_limiter_service.go
    ├── rate_limiter_service_interface.go
    ├── rate_limiter_service_test.go
    └── time_service.go
```

import section in main.go:

```
import (
    "MyExercise/controllers"
    "MyExercise/logging"
    "MyExercise/repositories"
    "MyExercise/services"
    "errors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)
```

Comment: try to do `go mod init YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` then `go mod tidy` before the go build command

Comment: Might be helpful if you could show your directory layout.  Looks like main.go is trying to import `MyExercise/controllers` which does not exist in your current project directory and is not in a well-known location like GOROOT either.

What is the relationship between `controllers` and `MyExercise/controllers`?

Comment: @GariSingh I added directory tree

Comment: @Kingindanord I tried. It didn't help :-(

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind also showing the imports section from `main.go` as well?

Comment: @GariSingh I edited the post and added the imports in go.main

Comment: If you `docker run --rm docker-gs-ping ls /app`, are the files where you expect them to be inside the image?  (You may need to remove the `*` from the `COPY` line; `COPY ./ ./`.)

Comment: Use a proper module name, "MyExercise" isn't. Use foo.bar.whatever if you are unsure.

Comment: Do you also see `/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.7/binding/msgpack.go:15:2: missing go.sum entry needed to verify package github.com/ugorji/go/codec (imported by github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding) is provided by exactly one module; to add:
        go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding@v1.7.7` in the error messages?

Comment: @GariSingh No. I don't see "missing go.sum in the errors".

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an issue with your Dockerfile.

`COPY ./* .`

does not actually do what you think.  It will copy all files recursively in a flat structure to the `/app` directory.

Modify your Dockerfile to something like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go env -w GO111MODULE=on

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/docker-gs-ping" ]
```

Basically, remove all of the `COPY` directives and replace with a single `ADD` directive

Comment: It still didn't help :-(

Comment: Hmm ... maybe also before running `docker build`, you might need to delete `go.mod` and `go.sum` and run `go mod init MyExercise` followed by `go mod tidy`

Comment: Like OP I followed instructions provided by Docker to create a [Go image](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/). Build worked for basic project, but when code was partitioned into packages, this error was produced:
<br>
    > docker build --platform x86_64 -t app .
    => ERROR [8/9] RUN go build main.go
    #16 0.783 main.go:8:2: package app/package is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/app/package)

Answer (score 0):

Do `go mod vendor` in your app directory. [Documentaion](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-vendor).

For build the container `docker build -t app:v1 .`

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app/

ADD . .

RUN go build -o /app/main

EXPOSE 5055

CMD [ "/app/main" ]
```

Comment: It also didn't help :-(

Comment: What's the error?